# Basic Constructive Modal Logic and Monoidal Endofunctors

Tags: modal-logic, intuitionistic-logic, categorical-logic

I'm reading this paper by Kakutani :

http://nicosia.is.s.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~kakutani/files/aplas07.pdf

but I can't see how to use naturality of $m$ (given by the monoidal endofunctor modelling $\Box$) to prove categorical soundness of the calculus defined in Table 2 of that paper.

Does it involve the definition of $m^\ast$ given in order to interpret the Box-rule? If so, how does it work?

Comment: Could it be that the last two equations in Table 2, involving `box`, correspond to the monoidal laws?

Comment: @frabala : Perhaps, but I'm not sure how to prove that.

Comment: Some questions, to better understand your question: Do you know how to start with this? Are you familiar with categorical models? Where exactly do you get stuck? Please, provide some more context.

Comment: @frabala : I solved it. The paper doesn't give an explicit definition of $m^{\ast}$, and that is confusing (in my opinion). After the correct definition of that morphism is recognised, the calculations are a bit tedious but sufficient to obtain the result. I am aware of categorical methods for this kind of calculi, and my only doubt was about that morphism. Thanks anyhow.